# Want to install CBLAS, but get the error " undefined reference to `pthread_atfork' "

Tags: python

I am trying to install CBLAS on Debian, for Numpy and Scipy on Python3.4.

I was referring to the web site:
http://osdf.github.io/blog/numpyscipy-with-openblas-for-ubuntu-1204.html
[http://www.kde.cs.tut.ac.jp/~atsushi/?p=493](http://www.kde.cs.tut.ac.jp/%7Eatsushi/?p=493)

First I have installed the OpenBLAS.

```
$git clone git://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS
$sudo vim /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf
$sudo ldconfig
$cd ~/Downloads/openBLAS
```

I have changed only the following two lines in "Makefile.rule". Other remains of default.

```
NO_CBLAS = 1
NO_LAPACK = 1
```

Return to the Shell, and make.

```
$ make
$ sudo make PREFIX=/usr/local install
$ sudo ldconfig
```

It was successful.

Next, I am trying to install CBLAS.

```
$wget http://www.netlib.org/blas/blast-forum/cblas.tgz
$tar xzf cblas.tgz
$cd ~/Downloads/CBLAS
```

And I have edited the Makefile.in as follows.

```
#
# Makefile.LINUX
#
#
# If you compile, change the name to Makefile.in.
#
#
 
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Shell
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

SHELL = /bin/sh

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Platform
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

PLAT = LINUX

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Libraries and includes
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
BLLIB = /usr/local/lib/libopenblas.a
CBLIB = ../lib/libcblas.a

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Compilers
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

CC = gcc
FC = gfortran
LOADER = $(FC) -lpthread

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Flags for Compilers
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

CFLAGS = -O3 -march=native -m64 -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -DADD_
FFLAGS = -O3 -march=native -m64 -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Archive programs and flags
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

ARCH = ar
ARCHFLAGS = cr
RANLIB = ranlib
```

Return to the shell, and make.

```
$make
```

However, such error messages are displayed.

```
ranlib ../lib/libcblas.a
make[1]: exit `/home/hiroakisuzuki/Downloads/CBLAS/src' 
( cd testing && make all )
make[1]: in `/home/hiroakisuzuki/Downloads/CBLAS/testing' 
gcc -I../include -O3 -march=native -m64 -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -DADD_ -c c_sblas1.c
gfortran -O3 -march=native -m64 -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -c c_sblat1.f
c_sblat1.f:214.48:

               CALL STEST1(SNRM2TEST(N,SX,INCX),STEMP,STEMP,SFAC)       
                                                1
Warning: Rank mismatch in argument 'strue1' at (1) (scalar and rank-1)
c_sblat1.f:218.48:

               CALL STEST1(SASUMTEST(N,SX,INCX),STEMP,STEMP,SFAC)       
                                                1
Warning: Rank mismatch in argument 'strue1' at (1) (scalar and rank-1)
gfortran -lpthread  -o xscblat1 c_sblat1.o c_sblas1.o ../lib/libcblas.a /usr/local/lib/libopenblas.a 
/usr/local/lib/libopenblas.a(memory.o): In function `openblas_fork_handler':
memory.c:(.text+0x2a0): undefined reference to `pthread_atfork'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [xscblat1] error 1
make[1]: exit `/home/hiroakisuzuki/Downloads/CBLAS/testing' 
make: *** [alltst] error2
```

I can not resolve the error. I want you to tell me if there is a solution.
I will be very grateful to the advice of everyone. Sorry for my poor English.

--This is my environmental --

- OS:Debian 7.6 wheezy
- CPU:Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU    Q9650  @3.00GHz
- GCC:gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5)
- GFORTRAN:GNU Fortran (Debian4.7.2-5) 4.7.2

---

Answer (score 0):

I too had come across the same error.

The call for `-lpthread` in the makefile is to be done soon after calling `libopenblas.a`. Right now, the opposite is happening.